# Python 3 openCV png overlay on a live preview of the camera

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm a very big noob to this type of program and I can't really find any type of help on this so I was asking if anyone had any tips for this sort of thing

Comment: what kind of overlay do you want? please give some example. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html) is a simple tutorial from OpenCV itself.

Comment: Tbe type of overlay is a static image on a live preview of the camera

Comment: Then refer to the tutorial, apply it to every frame from your camera. The documents also has tutorial on how to extract/grab frames from camera.

Comment: Ok so i tried the tutorial but it only shows how to blend 2 different images and not a image over the camera display

Comment: You need to grab each frame from the video and blend it as need be

Comment: Each frame on a live view camera? I think thats kinda impossible plus im not making it for a video its for a prototype scope